# Errors while using Qt to import manufacturer's dll for controlling motor controller hardware

Tags: c++, qt, dll, header

I'm trying to use Qt 5.3.1 on my Windows 7 64 bit machine to access a third party manufacturer supplied library for controlling a Performax Stepper Controller PMX-4EX-SA-TB9 that includes a .DLL, header, and lib file. I wrote a command prompt program in Visual C++ studio that linked up just fine but now I want to rewrite everything and use Qt to make a better looking program. I have my interface working and I haven't written any code that uses the library specifically, I've just been coding all the button magic thus far and now I want to make it operational.

My pro file looks like:

```
INCLUDEPATH += E:\qtTesting\ArcusTestInterface
QT          += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET   = ArcusTestInterface
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES  += main.cpp\
            mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h\
         += PerformaxCom.h
LIBS     += -LE:\qtTesting\ArcusTestInterface -lPerformaxCom
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

My lib, header, and dll file are all in the same folder with everything else and I've also put a copy of the DLL in the debug folder, trying to get things working. QtCreator has brought in the header file automatically to the project folder structure explorer and I can double click the file and see where my problems are for the build.

Here is a copy of the header file

```
#ifdef PERFORMAXCOM_EXPORTS
#define PERFORMAXCOM_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define PERFORMAXCOM_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern PERFORMAXCOM_API int nPerformaxCom;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

PERFORMAXCOM_API int fnPerformaxCom(void);

//USB reset

BOOL PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComUSBReset(IN HANDLE pHandle);
BOOL PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComFlush(IN HANDLE pHandle);

BOOL PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComGetNumDevices(OUT LPDWORD lpNumDevices);
BOOL PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComGetProductString(IN DWORD dwNumDevices, OUT LPVOID lpDeviceString, IN DWORD dwOptions);    
BOOL PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComOpen(IN DWORD dwDeviceNum, OUT HANDLE* pHandle);
BOOL PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComClose(IN HANDLE pHandle);
BOOL PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComSetTimeouts(IN DWORD dwReadTimeout, DWORD dwWriteTimeout);
BOOL PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComSendRecv(IN HANDLE pHandle, IN LPVOID wBuffer, IN DWORD dwNumBytesToWrite,IN DWORD dwNumBytesToRead,OUT LPVOID rBuffer);

signed int PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxMove(IN HANDLE pHandle, 
                                                    IN int commandCode, 
                                                    IN int axes,
                                                    IN int moveDir,
                                                    IN long *value,
                                                    IN int modelCode);

signed int PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxCommandReply(IN HANDLE pHandle, 
                                                             IN char *command, 
                                                             IN char *reply);

signed int PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxIO(IN HANDLE pHandle, 
                                                    IN int commandCode, 
                                                    IN int bitNumber,
                                                    IN long *value,
                                                    IN int modelCode);

signed int PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxMotorStat(IN HANDLE pHandle, 
                                                    IN int commandCode, 
                                                    IN int axes,
                                                    IN long *value,
                                                    IN int modelCode);

signed int PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxSpeedAccel(IN HANDLE pHandle, 
                                                           IN int commandCode, 
                                                           IN int axes,
                                                           IN long *value,
                                                           IN int modelCode);

signed int PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxGeneral(IN HANDLE pHandle, 
                                                        IN int commandCode, 
                                                        IN int axes,
                                                        IN long *value,  
                                                        IN int modelCode);


long PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComGetAxisStatus(IN HANDLE pHandle,DWORD dwAxisNumber);
long PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComGetPulseSpeed(IN HANDLE pHandle,DWORD dwAxisNumber);
long PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComGetPulsePos(IN HANDLE pHandle,DWORD dwAxisNumber);
BOOL PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComSetPulsePos(IN HANDLE pHandle,DWORD dwAxisNumber, DWORD pos);
long PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComGetEncoderPos(IN HANDLE pHandle,DWORD dwAxisNumber);
BOOL PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComSetEncoderPos(IN HANDLE pHandle,DWORD dwAxisNumber, DWORD pos);
BOOL PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComSetPolarity(IN HANDLE pHandle,DWORD dwAxisNumber,DWORD dwPolarity);
long PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComGetPolarity(IN HANDLE pHandle,DWORD dwAxisNumber);
long PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComGetDIOSetup(IN HANDLE pHandle);
BOOL PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComSetDIOSetup(IN HANDLE pHandle, DWORD dio_setup);
long PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComGetDIO(IN HANDLE pHandle);
BOOL PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComGetDIOBit(IN HANDLE pHandle,DWORD bitn);
BOOL PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComSetDIO(IN HANDLE pHandle,DWORD dio_value );
BOOL PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComSetDIOBit(IN HANDLE pHandle,DWORD bitn,DWORD bitv );
BOOL PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComDoHome(IN HANDLE pHandle,
                                                           DWORD axis,
                                                           DWORD dir,
                                                           DWORD low_speed,
                                                           DWORD high_speed,
                                                           DWORD accel_time,
                                                           DWORD decel_time,
                                                           DWORD search_mode,
                                                           DWORD ramp_mode);
BOOL PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComDoMove(IN HANDLE pHandle,
                                                           DWORD axisn,
                                                           DWORD target,
                                                           DWORD low_speed,
                                                           DWORD high_speed,
                                                           DWORD accel_time,
                                                           DWORD decel_time);
BOOL PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall fnPerformaxComStop(IN HANDLE pHandle,
                                                           DWORD axisn,
                                                           DWORD ramp_stop);






#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

My errors during building on line 38, the first line that starts like BOOL PERFORMAXCOM_API are: syntax error: 'int' should be preceded by ';' and missing type specifier - int assumed, and 'IN' : undeclared identifier and 'fnPerformaxComUSBReset' : definition of dllimport data not allowed.
Please help me. I have my interface all designed and i'm reading to start coding and I just can't get over this little curb.
Here is a screenshot of the errors:
[image: Error Screen Shot]

Thank You!

Comment: It is named Qt. QT is QuickTime.

Comment: The post has been edited, Silicomancer. Hopefully that will alleviate the confusion and allow people to help me solve my problem. I feel like I've followed every tutorial and technique for linking these files into Qt Creator but I'm getting 246 errors which I know are probably fixed with a line of code that I'm just overlooking.

Comment: Check your includes. IN is a windows macro, maybe you didn't include the necessary header (IN can be found in minwindef.h)?